# What can be used in a map literal instead of a type name in Go?

Tags: go

In 'A tour of Go' [there](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/21) is such phrase

> If the top-level type is just a type name, you can omit it from the
>   elements of the literal.

I'm new in Go so I'm curious when can not it be omitted?

```
var m = map[string]Vertex{
    "Bell Labs": {40.68433, -74.39967},    //top-level type is omitted
    "Google":    {37.42202, -122.08408},
}
```

Comment: The most common instance would probably be if `Vertex` is an interface type, you would have to include the type of the struct, array, slice, or map composite literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by commenter @TimCooper, if `Vertex` were an interface type then you would need to explicitly name the concrete type which implements the interface since the compiler couldn't reasonably guess which implementation you are referring to, for example:

```
type NoiseMaker interface { MakeNoise() string }

type Person struct {}
func (p Person) MakeNoise() string {
  return "Hello!"
}

type Car struct {}
func (c Car) MakeNoise() string {
  return "Vroom!"
}

// We must provide NoiseMaker instances here, since
// there is no implicit way to make a NoiseMaker...
noisemakers := map[string]NoiseMaker{
  "alice": Person{},
  "honda": Car{},
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. I just thought that top-level type something different.

Answer (score 0):

Also type can be omitted in a map literal when there is an anonymous struct

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var m = map[string]struct{ Lat, Long float64 }{
        "Bell Labs": {40.68433, -74.39967},
        "Google":    {37.42202, -122.08408},
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```